# Error while parsing UI hierarchy XML file: Invalid ui automator hierarchy file

Tags: appium, appium-android, uiautomatorviewer

I am frequently seeing this error in UI Automator Logs while trying to capture android device screenshot.I made sure appium server is not running when I run ui automator viewer.

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId:
>   file:/var/folders/pc/58zg75g541s_f3py_rz7qhhcshn3xw/T/uiautomatorviewer_2033080571607916566/dump_1556223184692823917.uix;
>   lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.    at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1472)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1014)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
>     at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:328)    at
>   com.android.uiautomator.tree.UiHierarchyXmlLoader.parseXml(UiHierarchyXmlLoader.java:130)
>     at
>   com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorModel.(UiAutomatorModel.java:51)
>     at
>   com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorHelper.takeSnapshot(UiAutomatorHelper.java:155)
>     at
>   com.android.uiautomator.actions.ScreenshotAction$1.run(ScreenshotAction.java:91)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
>   null rootnode after parsing.

Answer (score 1):

uiautomatorviewer in terminal opens corrupted automator.

Paste this in your terminal. It will open the correct Autmator

```
Android/Sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer
```

Answer (score 0):

Uiautomator gives this error too often

1. First solution is to disconnect and reconnect the device and perform same steps again

2.Use Appium inspector,it is more reliable and less error prone then uiautomator

Comment: Thanks Pankaj. I'm occasionally able to get it working. But problem is my appium script is also failing with a similar error.  [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Command returned error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read xml hierarchy: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected EOF (position:START_TAG @1:4097 in java.io.FileReader@ae7b834)
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":13,"value":"Could not read xml hierarchy: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected EOF (position:START_TAG @1:4097 in java.io.FileReader@ae7b834) "}

Comment: Can you paste ur code here, that will help me to understand better..expect delay in response!!

Comment: Like you said, issue magically disappeared now. I was seeing error when using xpath to locate element in appium 1.7.2, id for the same element worked though. But I don't see that issue anymore.